# How to seek video using dash.js?

Tags: javascript, dash.js

I am trying to play video in a HTML page.
But the video always play from the beginning.

I saved the time in a cookie and I am trying to play the video from that time.

There seems to be a `seek` function to achieve this?
How to play a video from a specific time using dash.js?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. The problem is probably that you are trying to seek before the player is ready. I came up with the following solution:

```js
dash?.on('streamInitialized', () => dash?.seek(time))
```

With this, seek works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since DashJS 4.4.1, you can now use attachSource() with a second parameter to seek to a specific time after the stream is initialized:

[attachSource(urlOrManifest, startTime)](http://cdn.dashjs.org/v4.4.1/jsdoc/module-MediaPlayer.html#attachSource__anchor)

> **startTime**     *number | string*
> For VoD content the start time is relative to the start time of the first period.
> For live content
> If the parameter starts from prefix posix: it signifies the absolute time range defined in seconds of Coordinated Universal Time (ITU-R TF.460-6). This is the number of seconds since 01-01-1970 00:00:00 UTC. Fractions of seconds may be optionally specified down to the millisecond level.
> If no posix prefix is used the starttime is relative to MPD@availabilityStartTime